# Filter what server returns

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using a form to post a betting ticket code to a server, and I get back something like this :

```
{"tick":[["4032497038600784","0","1.9","516.12","0","19","0","18.01.2014 12:01","0","0","","0"]]...
```

What language is this and how can I filter what the server returns in javascript and only show to the user important things about the matches he has on his ticket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response is a JSON string. You can parse it into JavaScript object using `JSON.parse` or `$.parseJSON` if you're using jQuery.

JSON.parse at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

**Edit:**

Seeing as you already use jQuery, you can post the form using ajax and get the response. Here's how you get the data:

```
$("#gettr").submit(function() {

    var url = "path/to/your/phpfile"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           dataType: "json",
           data: $("#gettr").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data) {
               // This is where your data wil be avalable. Do something with it here. No need to use JSON.parse as it is already parsed into a JS object.
               console.log(data)
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

jQuery.ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: How do I do that? The JSON comes from the server as plain text.No tags, no nothing....

This is what I use :
<div id="vtickhelp">
<div><h4>VERIFICA TICHET!</h4></div>
<form name="gettr" id="gettr" method="GET" action="*php file*">
                  <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="ro">
                  <input type="text" name="tickkey" id="tickkey" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Trimite">
<input type="reset" value="Anulare" onclick="$(&quot;#hereinfo&quot;).html(&quot;&quot;);">
                </form>
              </div>
And it comes as plain text o a single line of code.

Comment: What are you using to handle the response? jQuery?

Comment: I think I'll use jQuery.

Comment: If I use the script in the edit I get an error telling me to use POST method and if I put POST in the HTML, I get this "{"error": "Shell form does not validate"

Comment: Did you get a response while using `GET` in your form? If so, try changing ajax type to `GET`.

Comment: I tried that and i get this : "{"error": "Please use POST request"}", but if I use only the HTML, it sends me the JSON.

Comment: Try hard-coding your form data in ajax like this: `data: "lang=ro&tickkey=somevalidkey",`. If that doesn't work it has something to do with the server-side request processing.

Comment: Maybe...Because I don't have access to the server..I only use it the php file and cannot modify it...Thank you for everything!